# Is using [::-1] in python to reverse a list O(1) space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, time-complexity, reverse

So if I wrote:

```
item_list = item_list[::-1]
```

Would this be O(1) space? I think that item_list[::-1] results in the creation of a new list, so this might be O(n). Is item_list.reverse() then the proper method to reverse with O(1) space in python?

Comment: No, it creates a copy of the list, and requires linear space/time

Comment: I think, [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) will have O(1) complexity.

Comment: @Olvin sure, but not if you make a list out of it

Comment: @OlvinRoght: it is a *generator*. If you use `list(..)` over it, you make a copy, hence *O(n)* space.

Comment: Great, that you noticed that, so I've added link to docs where literally the same written.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem terminology nitpick, it returns an iterator, not a generator

Comment: Worth noting that slicing, such as `[::-1]` creates a shallow copy, so the space used by the new list depends only on the number of elements, and not what type of data it is storing.

Answer (score 10):

You are right that `some_list[::-1]` creates a *new* list, and that that list will have *n* "slots", and thus need *O(n)* memory.

Furthermore in [**CPython** [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython), an interpreter of Python, the `.reverse()` is done in *O(1)* memory. Indeed, if we look at the [`reverse` method [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c#L2492-L2505), we see:

> ```
> /*[clinic input]
> list.reverse
> Reverse *IN PLACE*.
> [clinic start generated code]*/
>
> static PyObject *
> list_reverse_impl(PyListObject *self)
> /*[clinic end generated code: output=482544fc451abea9 input=eefd4c3ae1bc9887]*/
> {
>     if (Py_SIZE(self) > 1)
>         reverse_slice(self->ob_item, self->ob_item + Py_SIZE(self));
>     Py_RETURN_NONE;
> }
> ```

It thus calls a function [`reverse_slice`, and this is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/listobject.c#L1059-L1073):

> ```
> /* Reverse a slice of a list in place, from lo up to (exclusive) hi. */
> static void
> reverse_slice(PyObject **lo, PyObject **hi)
> {
>     assert(lo && hi);
>
>     --hi;
>     while (lo < hi) {
>         PyObject *t = *lo;
>         *lo = *hi;
>         *hi = t;
>         ++lo;
>         --hi;
>     }
> }
> ```

It thus works with two pointers, one that iterates in ascending order, and one in descending order, and these "swap" values with each other, until they meet each other halfway.